# Can't Select username and password Column from user table (MySql)

Tags: php, mysql

I am putting up an authenticating system on my local server to test run some scripts for my personal use using PHP and MYSQL.  I ran the following code to select the 'username' and 'password' column from a 'users' table, but i kip getting this error after inputting the correct credentials:

```
Invalid username/password combination
```

Here is the script:

```
<?php // authentication.php 

require_once 'login.php';

$connection = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);


if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) &&
     isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {

        $un_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
        $pw_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un_temp' AND password='$pw_temp'";
        $result = $connection->query($query);
        if (!$result) die($connection->error);

    else if ($result->num_rows) {

        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
        $result->close();


            if ( password_verify( $pw_temp == $row[3]) ) {

                echo "$row[0] $row[1] : Hi $row[0], you are now logged in as '$row[2]'";

            }

        }

            else die("Invalid username/password combination");

     } else {

            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            die("Pleaser enter your username and password");
     }

    $connection->close();

    function mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $string) {

        return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($connection, $string));
     }

    function mysql_fix_string($connection, $string) {

        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
        return $connection->real_escape_string($string);
     }

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: If you're using `mysql_entities_fix_string` then you've got some serious problems here, that presumably hand-rolled function isn't sufficient.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: @tadman must you shout this advice at everyone all the time? Yes when it comes to creating public facing websites what you say is very true. However for someone who's struggling with the very basics, really do you think your advice is of any substance? These people need to learn the very basics before people like you start blowing their brains up telling them they MUST use a framework. Anyhoo, I quote his statement on line one of his question: **"I am putting up an authenticating system on my local server to test run some scripts for my personal use using PHP and MYSQL"**

Comment: @doug You're welcome to provide links of your own, but if you're going to shoot down the very idea of frameworks you're fighting a losing battle. PHP has a multitude of them, many are quite good, and using them facilitates learning in a way that banging against the core API never, ever will. I put this out there because personal projects often get deployed on public servers, shared with friends, and code like this can be cracked open by a bot in seconds. These warnings exist because the larger PHP community doesn't take these things seriously.

Comment: @tadman No no, I'm certainly not fighting against frameworks. I'm a Symfony fanatic personally. I'm just saying you spamming unsafe code questions with best practices is of no help for the questioner. My big negative toward learning the Framework first way, is developers come in the workplace and know exactly how to program the way abcFramework does it, but most workplaces don't use such a framework, which results in a programmer who knows not how to program PHP but simply how to do it the abcFramework way... These people need a foundation knowledge of the PHP before they goto a Framework IMO.

Comment: @doug I appreciate your feedback. The thing is I started a one person crusade against `mysql_query` some years back and it's developed into something of a movement where new coders are reminded of the risks of SQL injection bugs, obsolete APIs, and so on. This is taking it one step further. Using MD5 or fast hashes like it for passwords is simply not acceptable in this day and age. Writing your own login code is *always* trouble, even for experienced programmers, there's so many things that you can get wrong. A framework has you covered in most cases from the ugly side of those things.

Comment: @doug You're right that many frameworks are opinionated, or downright bizarre compared to others, but the *principle* of a framework is important here: They establish *conventions* and help people learn from good, well thought out examples. The biggest risk with core PHP is the multitude of astonishingly awful "tutorials" people will often fall victim to. In comparison the documentation for any given framework is typically more coherent, easier to learn from, and more up-to-date. It's a much better learning environment all around.

Comment: I really appreciate your observations @ tadman and @doug.  I am learning programming from scratch and felt i should learn the nitty gritty of it practically.  Kindly look into my code and tell me where I go wrong with regard to issue in question.

Comment: The problem here is that the token value doesn't match what you're expecting, but as you're writing your own super quirky password hashing algorithm you're basically going to have to figure it out for yourself if you want that particular method to work. If you replace it with [`password_hash`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) you won't have this problem and your passwords will actually be stored in a secure manner.

Comment: The most common problem here is that the password column you have is simply too short to store the complete hash value, and truncated values are going to mis-match.

Comment: Sorry ShallowGeek we've taken over your question. Essentially both tadman and I agree in principle but disagree on the right time to start. Personally I think you should learn the nitty gritty now, just don't produce anything for the public using what you learn at the moment. As far as your question goes, what does `print  $token; print $row[3];` result in?

Comment: @Doug, I just extracted the hashed password from the password column, and ran a password_verify() function in an if..else... statement, it printed: "Invalid Password."  It is likely the hashed value has been truncated.  So i updated the password column from VARCHAR(32) to VARCHAR(100),  and then re-ran the script, but still getting the same result as before.  How can I sort out the issue please?

Comment: I mean, print both the $token and $row[3] separately and compare the strings. If they are different then the way you are hashing the incoming password is wrong.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for the observation.  The hashed value of the password has been truncated indeed. I verified it using the password_verify().

Comment: One habit to kick before it hurts you more is making unnecessarily short columns. Use `VARCHAR(255)` for all string values unless you have a very compelling reason to limit it. This goes for names, email addresses, anything that's "just a string". It's only in cases where you know the content will absolutely be under a maximum length, for example IPv4 or IPv6 addresses, that you should limit things, and even then the limit is mostly cosmetic, it doesn't actually save any space as the only space used is for actual content, not the theoretical maximum length.

Comment: I updated the code by verifying the user's password with password_verify() against the hashed stored password created using the password_hash().

Comment: But i am still having the username/password error

Comment: Do keep in mind that the MySQL storage engine settings determines the number of columns a table can store and maximum row size, based on the total column size in bytes. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`password_verify` accepts the submitted password and its associated password hash, but is being supplied a boolean value (`$pw_temp == $row[3]`) See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php.

Assuming you use `password_hash` without a static salt to save the values in the database. Querying the password column is not possible, as `password_hash` will automatically salt passwords with a unique value. Which prevents you from comparing a second hash of the submitted value to the one in the database. So you would either need to store username as unique index or iterate over the duplicate usernames, and call `password_verify` to compare each user's password.

Assuming usernames are unique in your table, you should update your code to look like the following.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die("Please enter your username and password");
}
$un_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
$pw_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$un_temp'";
if (!$result = $connection->query($query)) {
    die($connection->error);
}
if (!$result->num_rows) {
    die("Invalid username/password combination");
}
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$result->close();
if (password_verify($pw_temp, $row[3])) {
    echo "$row[0] $row[1] : Hi $row[0], you are now logged in as '$row[2]'";
}
$connection->close();
```

[Demonstration](https://3v4l.org/HBNDW) Notice how each hashed password is different.
Keep in mind, since I am unable to query against a database, I used an array to show the equivalent process.

---

There were also a few syntax related issues in your original code, which would be a bit much to note in a comment.

`else if` should be one word so that it looks like `elseif` [[sic]](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) to avoid syntax conflicts, but since your condition results in calling `die()`, an `else` is not needed.

`isset` can verify multiple arguments, so calling it again in the same if comparison with `&&` is not needed [[sic]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Wrapping column and table names using identifier quotes (backticks), will help to avoid MySQL reserved keyword issues [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html).

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$un_temp' AND `password`='$pw_temp'
```

Lastly, due to the encryption algorithm and cost being subject to change between PHP security updates [[sic]](http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php#constant.password-default). When using `password_hash` and `password_verify`, you should always ensure the password is still cryptographically secure, by using `password_needs_rehash` [[sic]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) like so:

```
if (password_verify($password, $oldHash)) {
    //verify legacy password to new password_hash options
    if (password_needs_rehash($oldHash, \PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {
        //rehash/store plain-text password using new hash
        $newHash = password_hash($password, \PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $updateSQL = "UPDATE `users` SET `password`='$newHash' WHERE `username`='$un_temp' AND `password`='$oldHash'";
        $connection->query($updateSQL);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem.  I detected where I was wrong in the old code. I ran the script after updating it with what you posted and everything is fine now.  Thanks